# SQL Server Trigger using IF statements

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

How would I go about writing a Trigger that when an insertion to a particular table has been made, it checks for an attribute based on a condition and then append text to another attribute. How would I go about implementing the IF THEN logic to this?

```
    CREATE TABLE SomeTable (
      table_id NUMBER(5) NOT NULL
      paragraph varchar(50)
    );



 CREATE TRIGGER Append_Text ON SomeTable
    AFTER INSERT 
    AS
    BEGIN 

    /*pseudocode: if table_id = 5 then append text "mark watney" to paragraph*/ 

    END 
    GO
```

Comment: Two things.  One, the [sql] tag identifies database query question.  If you want to reference the Microsoft RDBMS product please use [sql-server] tag.  Two, by editing your question to remove the [oracle] tag you have rendered my answer pointless and your acceptance of it confusing to other users of this site.   If you didn't want an Oracle answer please say so.  If you want a SQL Server answer as well then say so.

Comment: handy tips, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an `instead of insert trigger`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Append_Text ON SomeTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO SomeTable
    SELECT table_id, paragraph + case when table_id = 5 then ' mark watney' else '' end 
    FROM INSERTED
END 
GO
```